# Unable to update through ajax in pagination using DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, pagination

I am using a Datatable plugin for using pagination on my HTML table. I have a checkbox to select different rows across different pages. Each row has a unique id. But when I need to update the row cells after ajax call, JS cannot recognize the element by ID if presently I am not on that row's page. It basically returns null when I do:-

```
document.getElementById('xyz').
```

The current page rows are updated but not the rows on other pages. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

DataTables row selector is optimised for IDs as it is natural to wish to select rows by unique information. This is distinct from a jQuery selector as DataTables can optimise this selector type so as to not involve the DOM - also allowing an id row selector to operate on rows which have not yet had their DOM nodes created (when using deferRender for extra speed).

With dynamically sourced data, the id assigned to the row is identifier using the rowId option. The data used as the id can be of any value, although it must be unique in the table.

To use an id selector, simply prefix the id value for the row you wish to select with a number sign: #. The value that follows is taken as the id. Unlike jQuery this value does not need to be escaped - although this means that an id selector must be used alone (e.g. a class name cannot also be used), it does make is much easier to use for complex data.

Select a single row by id:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
var row = table.row('#row-42');
```

Select multiple rows by id:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
var rows = table.rows( [ '#row-42', '#row-51' ] );
```

Source: https://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector